# What is 'deep-linkable' meaning in this context

Tags: javascript, angular

In school, we got a task to finish as pre-exam in Angular 9.
Our task is to do something similar as Trello, with Boards, Lists, Cards...

In task description, there is attention on **"boards, lists and cards should be deep-linkable"** but I am not sure what 'deep-link' should present in this case.

Can you please advise me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What is Depp Linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking)

The task asks that you can pass a link to a card, and enter directly to see the card, without having to do anything else, for example:

http://localhost:4200/cards/1  and this link should show you to the specific card

Comment: What is opponent situation, isn't it normal that every card will have different ID and that it will redirecto to /cards/1 .. /cards/2 etc ??

Comment: The difference is conceptual. That the cards have a deeplink is a requirement. If they did not say so, it is not necessary to make the link redirect directly to a card. You can handle the routing the way you like. But in this case, it's how you decide.

Comment: This is an example:
https://trello.com/c/NoqkmEln/538-document-that-by-convention-all-routes-in-a-sails-app-are-lowercased-currently-there-is-flexibility-here-this-is-about-documenti


This link, redirect you to a specific card